# How to convert number to date in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have column with value 44134 which is formatted as date time(yyyy/mm/dd) to 2020/10/30.

I am trying to convert this to have 2020/10/30 as value so that I can use in formulas. For this I tried to put this into a new column using formula

> Text(G2,"YYYY/MM/DD")

but this gives popup error "there is problem with the formula". There must be something really simple I am missing here. Excel has no problems formatting it right from the format menu but format doesn't change the underlying value. How do I get around this?

Comment: What formula are  you trying to use it in that doesn't currently work? Excel stores dates as numbers so 44134 and 30/10/2020 are the same value.

Comment: Excel can work with dates by default. `2020/10/30` will be read as `44134` so you can use it with no problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Rory I am basically trying to do like this ="INSERT INTO table_name('"&TEXT(G2,”dd-mm-yyyy”)"')" trying to generate insert query. But this too is saying there is problem with the formula.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I am basically trying to do like this ="INSERT INTO table_name('"&TEXT(G2,”dd-mm-yyyy”)"')" trying to generate insert query. But this too is saying there is problem with the formula.

Comment: What language Version of Excel are you using? What locale is your Windows using?

Comment: @AxelRichter office 365 64 bit (16.01.13801.21050) , date time region is set to english united states with date format as M/d/yyyy used inside VDI.

Comment: Try `="INSERT INTO table_name('"&TEXT(G2,"dd-mm-yyyy")&"')"`. You were missing an Ampersand in your formula at the end, for the scond single quote.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, maybe next time SuperUser would be more appropriate.  Also check out [ask] and also how to create a [mcve].  Anyway your code is missing a `&`... should probably be `="INSERT INTO table_name('"&TEXT(G2,"dd-mm-yyyy")&"')" `.

Comment: Seems as if your Excel uses semi colon as the attribute delimiter instead of comma. Try `=TEXT(G2;"YYYY/MM/DD")`

Comment: `="INSERT INTO table_name('"&TEXT(G2,”dd-mm-yyyy”)"')"` ... you are missing a second '&' I think. Try `="INSERT INTO table_name('"&TEXT(G2,"dd-mm-yyyy") & "')"` and also check the quotation marks '"' around dd-mm-yyyy, as when I paste the TEXT() part of the formula into Excel it causes an error, unless I change the quotation marks. Those quotes (”) you use are char(148) whereas the usual (") is char(34).

Comment: @AxelRichter It was '"&TEXT(G2|"YYYY/MM/DD")&"' . Delimiter was set to |      . Thanks I didn't know this part. This solved the issue now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I needed to check the delimiter.

As suggested in the comments

> '"&TEXT(G2|"YYYY/MM/DD")&"' worked for me in the end.